# What is the meaning of the song "9-29-045" by Green Carnation?

Tags: meaning, song-title

There is this beautiful song by `Green Carnation` called `"9-29-045"`. I've listened to this song many many times, but I've always wondered what the title means. Does anybody know why they named it `"9-29-045"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick look-up points to it being the date 9/29/1945, which was right around the time WWII ended.  Looking through the lyrics seems to hold this up.

> All the violence a man can take

Referencing the violence and cruelty of the war.

> Broken bones, and broken homes

Referencing what happens to families and countries when people get killed in war

> Yes I failed and I can't go back/
>   I'm wasted beyond my years

Talking about how war ages you and that veterans have flashbacks

[Source](http://www.metrolyrics.com/929045-lyrics-green-carnation.html)

Comment: This makes complete sense, I've never looked at it that way. Maybe because the "0" in "045" is a little misleading. You are smart! thank you ;)

Comment: Yeah, the 0 is an interesting choice.